# Table cell text has gap on top in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I can't seem to understand why, but even though I align it on the center of the cell in the layout tab, the text doesn't have equal spacing from the top and the bottom of the cell.
How to get rid of this?

[image: Here is the image to demonstrate]

Comment: Paragraph > Indents and Spacing > Before and After. http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/372x480xclip_image014.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.ql6gJxuq7-.png

Answer (score 1):

There is *horizontal* alignment and *vertical* alignment.

Left, Center, Right relates to *horizontal*; you need to use the Top, Middle, Bottom alignment.

In addition, it could be that you have a return in front of your text (which means there is a blank line above it), or the paragraph is set to '12 pt space above' or such. Set the paragraph to 0 above, 0 below.